# Dynamic fopen filepath in C

Tags: c, dynamic, fopen

```
char filePath[200];   
printf("Enter filepath: \n");
fgets(filePath, 200, stdin);
f = fopen(filePath, "r");   

while(!feof(f)) // crashed on this line
{

}
```

I cannot for some reason get this to work.
Please could some one point out what I am doing wrong on this.

Could you advice the correct way to write code for opening a filepath specified by user through command prompt?

Thanks,
Freddy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fgets` puts endline to the end of string (\r\n in Windows). So your filePath contains garbage at the end and file of that name doesn't exist. I would recommend to use `scanf("%[^\r\n]s", filePath)` instead. (`scanf` may differ on some implementations, please read your documentation.)

**update:** You should also ensure there won't be a buffer overflow by specifying buffer size. For example this way:

```
char filePath[100];
scanf("%99[^\r\n]s", filePath);
```

Comment: Bad advise - never ever ever use `scanf()` for user input.

Comment: This is fatally insecure unless you add a field width, and error-prone even then since you have to manually keep the field width and buffer size in sync (you can't use `sizeof`).

Comment: @Nikolai N Fetissov: `scanf` with a scan-set *can* be fine -- but in this case he's missed an important point: you *must* specify a maximum buffer size (what he has right now is essentially equivalent to `gets`). Also note that with a scanset, you do *not* need an "s" following the closing brace as he shows above.

Comment: I guess you are right. I have just never seen anybody teaching scansets, to the extent that people are not even aware such functionality exists.

Comment: Thanks guys for valuable advice. I realise the sscanf is better than scanf. But, I suppose specifying the buffer size, makes it slightly better.

Answer (score 2):

[`fopen(3)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/fopen.3.html) returns `NULL` if it cannot open the file. You should always check for that. [`fgets(3)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/fgets.3.html) does that too, but your problem is probably the new-line character that it keeps in the returned string.

Comment: I understand what you are saying. But, how would that code look like if you were to modify my code above. I'm quite new to C you see.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
size_t l = strlen(filePath);
if (filePath[l-1] == '\n') filePath[--l-1] = 0;
if (filePath[l-1] == '\r') filePath[--l-1] = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You check the error code from fgets and fopen.  Both return null if they failed